# When are there $n$ elements in $\mathbb{Z}_n^2$ with all differences distinct?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, geometry, combinatorial-geometry, discrete-geometry

For which natural number $n$ are there elements $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n \subset \mathbb{Z}_n^2$ such that $x_i - x_j = x_k - x_l$ if and only if $i = k$ and $j=l$ (i.e. such that all differences between the elements are distinct)?

Such elements do not exist for $n=2$ and $n=3$. But they exist for example for $n=4,5,6$. E.g. for $n=4$ take the elements $\{(\bar{0}, \bar{0}), (\bar{1},\bar{0}), (\bar{2}, \bar{1}), (\bar{1}, \bar{3})\}$.

The problem of finding $n$ points with distinct differences in a given rectangular subset of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ has been investigated a lot. Unfortunately, this is not the case for the modular formulation presented above.
The best reference I could find is this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0811.3832), section V. There, they construct similar subsets of $\mathbb{Z}_n^2$ using e.g. Golomb Rulers (also known as Sidon sets). The closest result to the question posed above is Theorem 20, but it is not strong enough.

Does anyone know where I could find answers to the question above?

Thank you!

Antropath

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Sorry, I meant "differences" instead of "distances" in the titel (I corrected it). So, I want that the distance vectors between two points are always different (modulo $n$). For example, for my example for $n=4$ above the difference vector $(\bar{2},\bar{1}) - (\bar{1},\bar{0}) = (\bar{1},\bar{1})$ only appears once as a difference of two points.

Comment: And thank you for the thread. But since I am looking for distinct differences (not distances) these methods cannot really be applied to the current problem.
For the problem of finding $n$ points with distinct distances there is quite a lot of literature. E.g. some work by Erdös; see also https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/11/20/the-guth-katz-bound-on-the-erdos-distance-problem/.

Comment: Ok. Now everything makes sense :-) Assuming $i\neq j$ and $k\neq\ell$ to exclude trivial cases. So altogether $n(n-1)$ non-zero differences in a group of $n^2-1$ non-zero elements, which is a tight fit and may or may not be possible. Deleting my old comments.

Comment: Yes, $n$ is the largest number of elements for which all differences can be different.
I wonder if there is some other counting argument/non-constructrive argument that allows to prove that $n$ such elements are always possible for $n>3$.

Comment: I asked essentially the same question (see link below). Someone pointed out that what I was looking for is called a "Sidon set" after searching I found that you asked the identical question! Were you ever able to find more information on this topic?  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3491165/finding-n-elements-of-mathbbz-n-times-mathbbz-n-such-that-their-differe

Comment: Unfortunately I never really found good information about this problem. Eventually I circumvented it in my research.